# Store encrypted user credentials in json web token?

Tags: security, encryption, jwt

I know it's not best practice, but I'd like to store username and password in a json web token after initial authentication. Of course those credentials will be encrypted before passing them to the jwt payload.
The reason for this approach is that my api exchanges information with a third party which relies on username/password authentication only (no tokens). So every time I make a request from my client, the api has to pass the user credentials to the third party.

Is this safe or can anybody think of a better way to do this?

Comment: You should really consider to stop using this third party, all your customer will be hacks because of it, speak to your security team. ELSE read about oAuth2

Comment: Hey Jacques, what exactly do you mean with hacks? How would that work? All communication is SSL-encrypted. The token payload with the credentials is encrypted. What am I missing? In this particular case oAuth2 is no option btw.

Comment: I'm wondering about this too. We have multiple apps that share the same in-house JWT-based auth library. One of them needs to have access to the initial login/password for accessing SMB stores.